# Basic question on powering a DC motor

Tags: power-supply, voltage, brushless-dc-motor

I'd like to use my ATX PSU to power a DC motor Turnigy L2205_1350 motor
Voltage: 7.2v~11.1v (2s~3s)
Max Power: 100w
Max Current: 13.5A
No load Current: 0.3A

Can I connect to 12V+ on the PSU?  I noticed Max AMPS of the 12V is below 13.5 motor's max current.

Would if be better to connect the motor to the PSU's 3.3V and 5V connectors?

Motor: http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__14739__Turnigy_L2205_1350_Brushless_Motor_100w_.html

Comment: It is BLDC. You can't work with it without a controller.

Answer (score 1):

Eugene is right, you can't do that. I am both an engineer but started out in RC like you I'm assuming. Yes, the power is being provided by a DC battery but that is an AC motor. The speed controller (ESC) used in RC cars and planes is what converts the battery's DC voltage to AC to control the motor, hence 3 wires (3 phases) to the motor instead of just 2 (+ and -) to a DC motor.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm a newbie, actually a SW Engineer.  Just now playing with hardware as a hobby.  This is to power a fan created via 3d printer: http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:437314    I was looking for a cheap way to power this centrifugal fan.  I only want to run at max speed the current will allow w/o over powering the motor.  This will only run as a demo / amusement.  So could I put an ESC between the PSU's  DC current and this motor?

Comment: Even if you use an ESC used in RC cars/planes, you'd then need to find a way to control that since they use receivers/transmitters. If you want to use that motor, you'd probably be better off controlling it with an Arduino and a brushless motor control shield. However, probably the very easiest thing would be to use a DC motor powered by a DC voltage, then you need no controller at all.  Cool project, good luck!